# Append data to end of each line using unix variable through sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file and I want to append the value in a unix variable at the end of each line using SED.

I have already achieved this through AWK but I would like to do it in SED

something like this. I have already tried the below command and it's not working.

```
sed -i 's/$/"$BATCH_RUN_DATE"/g' data.csv
```

**Error**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
```

GNU sed version 4.2.1

Regards,
Aswinikumar

Comment: What is your problem? Have you tried the sed command you showed? What is its output?

Comment: @user3792699 : Please format code in question. In such cases, it is expected to give a sample input/output. `It's not working` doesn't explain anything at all..

Comment: Since, it is a date and sed complains about an unknown option, I guess, the date (`$BATCH_RUN_DATE`) contains slashes. This collides with sed's separators. In this case, you must use a different separator, like comma or exclamation mark, e.g. `sed -e "s!$! ${BATCH_RUN_DATE}!" data.csv`

Answer (score 3):

here is an example of how you could do it:

```
% cat subject.txt                     
Studid    StudName     Asp.Net   DBMS     Unix
   1       Ani         75        62       80
   2       George      90        95       82
   3       Jake        45        30       40
   4       Dennie      89        92       90
% 
% my_var="R2D2"                       
% 
% sed "s/$/${my_var}/" subject.txt 
Studid    StudName     Asp.Net   DBMS     UnixR2D2
   1       Ani         75        62       80R2D2
   2       George      90        95       82R2D2
   3       Jake        45        30       40R2D2
   4       Dennie      89        92       90R2D2
```

#### Explanation

The tricky thing about this `sed` expression, is *why don't I need to reinsert the `$` newline in the replace part of the substitution?*.
I believe this is because when `sed` loads each line into the pattern space it removes the newline, then after all pattern space operations, it then re-attaches a newline to the contents of the pattern space then prints the pattern space, so I guess the newline is a kind of a "freebie" here.
Then you might ask the question, how does the first `$` match if the pattern space has no newline in it ? -- if I had to guess, I might say , `sed` just knows what you mean when you use the `$` meta character, but that is just a guess.

Comment: sed "s/$/${BATCH_RUN_DATE}/g" data.csv
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'

I have already this and it's not working. Got the above error message

Answer (score 1):

You should put the script itself inside double quotes if you wish bash variable expansion to happen

```
sed -i "s/$/$BATCH_RUN_DATE/" data.csv
```

should do the job. This is the most easiest way to do it. Also, note you don't need the global flag as there is only one substitution per line.

**Sidenotes**

- Check if your `sed` supports inplace edit option
- Check if `$BATCH_RUN_DATE` itself is non-empty.

Comment: I have already tried that it's not working

Comment: You must quote the first `$`.

Comment: @user3792699 : What version of sed are you using? Some may not support the `-i` option. In that case you need to do `sed "s/$/$BATCH_RUN_DATE/" data.csv > tempfile && mv temp data.csv`

Comment: This is a very common answer. Please flag as a duplicate instead of answering, so that we collect all good anwers in a single place. The [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info) contains a collection of common questions for this tag. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @OlafDietsche I have tried that too. Not working

sed "s/'$'/$BATCH_RUN_DATE/g" data.csv

ErrorMessage: : -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @OlafDietsche : May I know what is that for?

Comment: @sjsam It's having date value and I have done this using AWK but I want to do in sed

Comment: @user3792699 : May I know what is the error you got when you run my command?

Comment: @sjsam My mistake, I thought `$/` will be interpreted as a variable.

Comment: @sjsam Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'